# SQL combining multiple results to one table with Sums

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have the following stored procedure working. It sums up records in a given year (2013) on a specific TIN. The TINS have a Taxpayer name identified with the TIN along with the results.
The columns render out as TIN, TaxpayerName, Total.

This is an accounting based application.

What I would like to do is add a 4th column that will show the sum of another year, so these can be compared to later. The year will always be the preceeding year (2012 in this example).

There may or may not be any entires for the previous year, so I have to give it a 0 or null for the previous year. I am struggling to figure out how to combine them together.
Somehow I am going to have to match each TIN and get the sum of the previous year if it exists.
The portion of this query will look something like this: Trans.Main_AbstractNumber =136 and SUBSTRING(Trans.Main_TaxPeriod,1,4) = '2012', Using SUM(Main_AbstractAmount) as PreviousTotal or something like that.

Does anyone have any idea how I should approach this?
Thank you

```
 Select Trans.Main_TIN, C.TaxpayerName, SUM(Main_AbstractAmount) as Total  
 from qetl.RECORDS Trans join qetl.TAXPAYERS C on Trans.Main_TIN=C.TIN  
 where Trans.Main_AbstractNumber =136 and SUBSTRING(Trans.Main_TaxPeriod,1,4) = '2013'  
 GROUP BY Trans.Main_TIN,C.TaxpayerName
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use conditional summation:

```
 Select Trans.Main_TIN, C.TaxpayerName,
        SUM(case when SUBSTRING(Trans.Main_TaxPeriod,1,4) = '2013' then Main_AbstractAmount end) as Total2013,
        SUM(case when SUBSTRING(Trans.Main_TaxPeriod,1,4) = '2012' then Main_AbstractAmount end) as Total2012
 from qetl.RECORDS Trans join
      qetl.TAXPAYERS C
      on Trans.Main_TIN=C.TIN  
 where Trans.Main_AbstractNumber = 136  
 GROUP BY Trans.Main_TIN, C.TaxpayerName ;
```